# How to use TWIC files for study

Tags: study

I'd like some feedback and suggestions on how you use The Week In Chess pgn/cbv files for study. Here are a few things I do with them:

**1. Play from a won position** - here we go down the list of decided games and using a chess engine, get to the point in the game where the evaluation flips to +/- 2.00 or greater. Play the game out at that point against the computer and try and find a winning continuation.

**2. Update your repertoire** - Using the ECO Keys, gather the games in your main repertoire from the TWIC file and at least review those games and possibly add them to your repertoire games database. This allows you to see potential new ideas and how to play certain middle-games coming out of your repertoire.

**3. Hold the Draw** - Take a drawn game and jump in and play it against the computer and try and hold the ending with 10-20 moves left. Try it from both sides, alternatively. This ii a great way to understand endgame play.

**4. Defend your King** - this is the opposite of #1 - Take the losing position and try to defend it. You might want to consider reducing the +/- to  a pawn down on the comp. valuation. This is good defensive practice when in a worse position.

Just some thoughts...

Comment: I mainly use TWIC to update and maintain a database, to use for searches and opening statistics. I don't see the big point in using TWIC games for training against computers. Why not just play regular games against human opponents?

Comment: The idea is to work on specific aspects of your game. It's hard to work on Rook Endgames against online opponents during play - you may not get one all night. Get the idea?

Comment: I get it, but I'm still sceptical. Why use TWIC specifically, instead of just any other collection of games, except for opening reference? Also, computers are not the ideal training partners, in my opinion. The way a computer plays does not resemble the way a human plays. It's better to analyze the positions(without computer aid) to some detail, if you want specific training.

Comment: Because TWIC is new, fresh, in cbv format, and easily accessible. And I disagree - computers are the ideal training partner for these kinds of exercises - tireless, always available, and easy to record your results. Analyzing the position is not part of the exercise. Learning how to play fresh positions under a game simulation is the idea. The computer is a tool to be used, not scorned. But, to each his own.

Comment: Except for your second point (update repertoire) I don't see what is specific about TWIC. You could use just about any other database of high level games, no? Playing from a won/drawn/defensive position should be the same whether the games was played 20 years ago or last week. What is so amazing about the cbv format?

Answer (score 4):

Grandmaster Larry Christiansen recommends studying 200 recent games per week from games that relate to your opening repertiore.  TWIC is ideally suited for doing that.

Comment: Really studying (or glancing over)? That's a lot of work for one week. For what kind of people does he recommend that?

Comment: I believe he is saying that is what Grandmaster's do or people who are training to become very strong players.  I believe most masters would recommend for someone with less knowledge or motivation to study games for understanding.  Still TWIC is good for any level because you can find a game between strong players that relates to new developments in your opening so it can help you to not to get caught in the opening with the latest theory and help you to better understand what are the best ideas are in your opening.

Comment: I used to train with a strong IM and he told me to really study 14 games per week but to glance over at least 100 games per week and to come up with a novelty once a month (I could use a chess engine to help me fine tune this)